# How to find loop number in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to get the question number in this loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="quizqs in Quizdata.questions">
    <li ng-click="form.goTo(Form, 1)">
        <a href ng-class="{'selected' : currentStep >= 1, 'done' : currentStep > 1}">
            <div class="stepNumber"> 1 </div>
            <span class="stepDesc text-small">Question No {{quizqs.id}} - {{Quizdata_Lenght}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{{$index}}`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-repeat="quizqs in [12,43,354,13,653]">
    <li ng-click="form.goTo(Form, 1)">
      <a href ng-class="{'selected' : currentStep >= 1, 'done' : currentStep > 1}">
        <div class="stepNumber">
        </div> <span class="stepDesc text-small">Question No {{$index}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To get the loop number or loop id in a *loop*, the AngularJS has an in-built variable known as - `$index`

This `$index` can only be used with `ng-repeat` in either the HTML files or in the directives (like `filter`, `ng-include`, custom-directives, etc.)

*Remember*: `$index` starts from 0, so whenever you wish to start from 1, you need to increment by one.

*Code below:*

```
<div class="stepNumber">
          {{index}}
</div>
<span class="stepDesc text-small">Question No: {{$index + 1}}</span>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/szhsns30/)**